# Displaying associated model data in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller, associations

I have two models set up: Photo and Search. Each photo has one associated search, and I want to try and display this associated search in the photo view. Here are my models:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :search

end

# Data: name:string, photo_url:string, search_id:integer
```

Brief aside: I’m unsure whether I need to have the has_many association here or not.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :search_term, :presence => true
  has_many :photos

end

# Data: search_term:string
```

Here is the controller action:

```
def index
  @photos = Photo.all
end
```

And finally, the view templates:

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->

<section class="photos">
  <%= render @photos %>
</section>

<!-- _photo.html.erb -->

<div class="photo__item">
  <h1><%= photo.id %>: <%= photo.name %></h1>
  <h3>Search_term: <%= photo.search_id.search_term %></h3>
  <%= image_tag(photo.photo_url) %>
</div>
```

The error I’m getting is:

```
undefined method `search_term' for 2:Fixnum
```

I’m not even entirely sure my set up for this is correct, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put the search_id in the photos table, so i think you should make the photo class definition like this

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :search
end
```

and in the view you you should get the photo's search instance like this

```
<h3>Search_term: <%= photo.search.search_term %></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct association. Try changing `has_one :search` to `belongs_to :search`.

> The belongs_to association is always used in the model that has the foreign key.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Ah, I’m with you. Which parts should I change in the controller and views?

Comment: Try photo.search.search_term`